# RavenDB: is there a way to remove the concrete field from DB?

Tags: c#, json, database, ravendb

I have such a Raven db document structure:

```
{"Title":"abc",
"User":{"$type": "IOM.Server.Data", "Mail":...etc},
"Content": [
   {
      "Additional": {
         "Title": "abc",
         "$type": "IOM.Server.Data"
      }
   }]
}
```

In Visual Studio (C#) I get an error "Can't load assembly 'IOM.Server.Data'".

I can't read this value as String, because I can't have a variable called "$type".

And now I have to read User and Content as Object type and then convert to Json and then get the information from Json Objects. It would be much easier, if I could just remove all these fields from everywhere (User, Content-Additional) in db as I don't need them. Is there a way of doing that? Is it right to solve the problem like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you see $type in the studio it means that you probably have instantiate 'User' and 'Additional' with a class that extend the base class of your props 'User' and 'Additional'.
By the way if you want to remove $type you can use patch:

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Patch("yourDocId/1",
                    new[] 
                    { 
                        new PatchRequest
                        {
                            Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                            Name = "User",
                            AllPositions = true,
                            Nested = new []
                            {                                   
                                 new PatchRequest
                                 {
                                      Type = PatchCommandType.Unset,
                                      Name = "$type"
                                 }                                    
                            }
                        },
                        new PatchRequest
                        {
                            Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                            Name = "Content",
                            AllPositions = true,
                            Nested = new []
                            {
                                new PatchRequest
                                {
                                    Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                                    Name = "Additional",
                                    AllPositions = true,
                                    Nested = new []
                                    {
                                        new PatchRequest
                                        {
                                            Type = PatchCommandType.Unset,
                                            Name = "$type"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes. You are right. I found the 'IOM.Server.Data' assembly on customer's server and it contained everything I needed. Basically, it solved everything. Thank you